# Import data from an excel file in a 1:N relationship

Tags: dynamics-crm, one-to-many, microsoft-dynamics, import-from-excel

Is it possible to import data in an a 1 to many relationship. I have an entity "Rent Roll" which is having N:1 relationship with opportunity. "Rent Roll" is a custom entity.  An opportunity can have multiple rent and rolls. I already have data in "Opportunity" and "Rent Roll". Is there a way by which I can fill the below "Rent Roll" grid? I want to export this data from XLS because its a huge list of records and doing manually (by clicking + button) would take long time.

This is an Opportunity page screenshot. The Rent Roll entity is shown as a Grid here. In this picture no Rent Roll objects exist at the moment. But the objects already exist in Rent Roll entity.

[image]

Comment: Export "Rent Roll", fill lookup, reimport

Comment: This will only fill data in Opportunity field of Rent Roll (Lookup field). Still the Rent Roll field in Opportunity remains empty (1:M) relationship.

Comment: What rent roll field ? It's 1:M, there is no such thing.

Comment: Yes its 1:M. So is there any possibility to populate this field from XLS/CSV or any third party plugin or application based on existing data in Dynamics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a 1:N relationship from Opportunity to Rent Roll, this means you have an Opportunity lookup field on the Rent Roll entity. I am guessing you want the Rent Roll data (multiple tenants) all on the same opportunity, which is your **"test data"** opportunity record. Here are the steps you should take:

1. Open Advanced Find and change the "Look For" Dropdown to be "Rent Roll"
2. Click Edit Columns, and make sure the Opportuntiy field is there, as well as all the other fields you need to import from your data source.
3. Click Results - this will probably result in no records found which is ok
4. Click Export Rent Roll spreadsheet icon (top right corner) and choose static worksheet - this should download an Excel template called Rent Roll Advanced Find View.xlsx. Close the advanced find window. Make a **copy** of the template for future use.
5. Using the template, copy/paste data from your source system into the template. You can delete rows, but do not add or delete any columns.
6. In the Opportunity Name column, enter **Test Data** for all rows.
7. Save and close the spreadsheet.
8. In Dynamics, navigate back to the opportunity view
9. Click the Import Data Icon on the top of the screen (or under the "...")
10. Choose the template file to import. This should give you a series of import steps to load the data into the Rent Roll table.
11. After you click Finish on the import wizard, wait several minutes and the data should appear on your Rent Roll subgrid on the Test Data opportunity.

If your data does not appear, navigate to the Settings/Data Management/Data Import view and see if you had errors on the import.